# How to configure the date format in PnP Modern Search

Tags: search

How can I configure the date format in the search results webpart? (from "October 14, 2022" to"14.10.2022")?

I tried OWSModifiedDate but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I guess you using a resent version of PnP Modern Search Web parts.  In that case you should be able to tweak the format using handlebars,  like {{getDate StampDateOWSDATE "DD/MM/YYYY" 0 true}